Binding issues with CollectionView
I have a collection view with an external view for the DataTemplate. The views show for the CollectionView with the data correctly bound (it's not using a VM fas it's simple app). The data model that fills the CollectionView contans a property called Id (an int). This is fed as the ClassId for the Frame within the ContentView used by the DataTemplate.
I've added a SelectionChanged event to the CollectionView which fires fine. However, when I examine the object passed in, it looks like the ClassId is not being propogagated to the ContentView selected.
My code in the event looks like this
void ItemSelected_Clicked(object? sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var template = ((CollectionView)sender).ItemTemplate;

     var frame = (CollectionTemplateView)template.LoadTemplate();
     if (frame != null)
     {
         var theframe = frame.Content;
         if (theframe.BackgroundColor is null)
         {
             MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => theframe.BackgroundColor = Colors.Beige);
         }
     }
 }

If I set a break point on the inner if, the ClassId is null. If I set the ClassId in the ContentView to be some text, it shows fine (so it is the correct View).
ClassId is a bindable property, so I'm not sure if I've uncovered a bug here in MAUI.
Oddly, setting the background colour also has no effect on the Frame either. Am I missing something here?

Kindly post your Xaml code if possible

https://pastebin.com/1eEsqE5E for the contentview. The CollectionView is a bog standard collection view

Sorry I can not answer your question, however, I posted Question Extension and Suggested Solutions, hope some one else continue with the full answer.

Question Extension and Suggested Solutions
You could use:
<Frame.GestureRecognizers >
    <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type CollectionView_Templated.Views.CollectionTemplateView}},Path=MyCommand}"/>                      
</Frame.GestureRecognizers>-->

OR
<Frame CornerRadius="8" BorderColor="LightBlue" Padding="0,4" ClassId="hello" x:Name="frame">
    <Frame.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Frame}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Frame" Binding="..." Value="...">
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Beige"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
</Frame.Style>
...
...
</Frame>

OR DataTemplateSelector as suggested by @KISHOR RAGURAM G CSE
Xaml code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CollectionView_Templated.Views.CollectionTemplateView" >

    <CollectionView HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding OB_ItemModel}" 
          SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="ItemSelected_Clicked" >
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate >

                <Frame CornerRadius="8" BorderColor="LightBlue" Padding="0,4" ClassId="hello" x:Name="frame">
                    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="20*,80*" ClassId="{Binding Id}" >
                        <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="auto,auto, *" Grid.RowDefinitions="auto, auto,auto,auto,auto">
                                <Label Text="Route number" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" WidthRequest="100"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding RouteNumber}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                <Label Text="From" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding From}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>

            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentView>

Code Behind.cs
namespace CollectionView_Templated.Views;

public partial class CollectionTemplateView : ContentView
{
    public CollectionTemplateView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;

        OB_ItemModel.Add(new ItemModel()
        {
            Id = 1,
            RouteNumber = "RouteNumber No.1",
            From = "From No.1"
        });
        OB_ItemModel.Add(new ItemModel()
        {
            Id = 2,
            RouteNumber = "RouteNumber No.2",
            From = "From No.2"
        });
        OB_ItemModel.Add(new ItemModel()
        {
            Id = 3,
            RouteNumber = "RouteNumber No.3",
            From = "From No.3"
        });

    }
    public class ItemModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
        public string RouteNumber { get; set; } = "";
        public string From { get; set; } = "";
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> OB_ItemModel { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();

    private void ItemSelected_Clicked(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var template = ((CollectionView)sender).ItemTemplate;

        var frame = (CollectionTemplateView)template.LoadTemplate();
        if (frame != null)
        {
            var theframe = frame.Content;
            if (theframe.BackgroundColor is null)
            {
                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => theframe.BackgroundColor = Colors.Beige);
            }
        }
    }
}

